# How to give endpoint address in standardendpoint element tag in wcf?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

in my local machine services are running fine.but while placing published files to other system then services are not running.please tell me.my web.config file is below.please tell me where to give endpoint addresses.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!--
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint   name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="TestDataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AMI.csdl|res://*/AMI.ssdl|res://*/AMI.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=Venkat-PC;Initial Catalog=TestData;User ID=sa;Password=p@ssw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define endpoint address for standard endpoint. Standard endpoint is just a template applied on the real endpoint. The real endpoint in your case should be defined by your hosted web application (url of your application) and routes defined in your Global.asax (relative part of your url).